# JPA map relations related to different classes

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have one question related to JPA relations.

Is it possible to define one relation to different classes?

Ej: `Foo` has a `one-to-one` relation (or `many-to-one`) with `Boo` or `Too` class (both can extend the same abstract class) but not a relation with both at the same time.

Thanks!

More details

It will be something like:

```
@Entity
class Foo {
@Id
int id;
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="MOO_ID")
Moo moo;
}

Interface Moo{}

@Entity
class Too implements Moo{}
@Entity
class Boo implements Moo{}
```

And my database needs only one reference to the correct table Too or Boo.

Comment: JPA has inheritance, but the important part is - what do you want the database structure to look like?

Comment: I would like to do something like: Foo has one Boo or one Too but not both. My database need a FK to the correct table Boo table or Too table.

Comment: Are Boo and Too of the same type, or do they share a supertype?

Comment: I think DataNucleus JPA supports interfaces in relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you made Moo an abstract class and specified an inheritance strategy you could achieve this.

i.e.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Moo  {
   @Id int id;
}
```

and then for Foo:

```
@Entity
class Foo {
  @Id
  int id;

  @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="MOO_ID")
  Moo moo;
}
```

And

```
@Entity
class Too extends Moo{}

@Entity
class Boo extends Moo{}
```

That way the Moo reference can be either Boo or Too.

You should also thenn choose whichever inheritance strategy works best for your scenario. From TABLE_PER_CLASS, SINGLE_TABLE and JOINED.